# Corrupt Graphics on Pixel XL and Xiaomi Mi 6

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a minimal sample project that produces corrupt graphics on a Google Pixel XL and a Xiaomi Mi6, but works correctly on a Samsung Galaxy S6.

Setting android:hardwareAccelerated=false fixes the corrupt graphics but leads to issues with animations and scrolling leaving trails.

The sample project uses MvvmCross, however I have been able to reproduce the behaviour without MvvmCross.

The project code can be found at https://github.com/stevedcc/Xamarin_Broken_Graphics.git

View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mainLogo"
    android:src="@drawable/company_logo_1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_below="@drawable/main_image1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="?attr/main_image"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainScanText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/main_image"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="Title" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <attr name="company_logo" format="reference" />
  <attr name="main_image" format="reference"/>
  <attr name="company_color" format="reference" />
  <attr name="splash_background" fromat="reference" />
  <color name="company_color_1">#7f7f7f</color>
  <style name="CompanyTheme" 
          parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
    <item name="company_logo">@drawable/company_logo_1</item>
    <item name="main_image">@drawable/main_image1</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#000000</item>
    <item name="company_color">@color/company_color_1</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHN5I.png) as displayed by a Galaxy S6

[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NTfW.png) as displayed by a Pixel XL

Can anyone tell me how to fix the Corrupt graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">#000000</item>
```

leads to the issue, if replaced by

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/black</item>
```

then the project works.

Comment: I investigated this in Android Studio, to determine if it's a Xamarin bug or not - I could succesfully reproduce the issue in Android studio.